# How to publish ASP.Net website to remote machine?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am trying to publish the ASP.Net site in IIS to a remote machine.
Presently I am publishing the site local file system and copying that folder to remote machine using mstsc tool.

Is there any way I can directly publish to remote machine?

Comment: Yes - you can use msdeploy - see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd568996(v=ws.10).aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is,

1. You have to make sure `web deployment service` is running on your server. You can check these articles to find out how to install the web deployment. [Here](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy) or [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-server-environments-for-web-deployment/configuring-a-web-server-for-web-deploy-publishing-%28web-deploy-handler%29).
2. Once your `web deployment service` is running and configured you need to configure your publishing settings. In *Visual Studio* right click on your solution project, choose `Publish` and select the `Web deploy` or `Web deploy package` as your `publish method` setting. Good article describing *web deployment scenarios* can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Hope that helps you.